# How to write a shell script to find min max and average from sar reports for ram utilization

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have written a shell script to find avg, min and max values from sar report for command `sar -r -f` as below

```
MIN1=`sar -r -f |awk '{print $5}'|grep -v '%memused'|awk 'min=="" || $0 < min {min=$0} END{ print min}'`

MAX1=`sar -r -f |awk '{print $5}'|grep -v '%memused'|grep -v '_x86_64_'|grep -v '86327'|awk 'min=="" || $0 > min {min=$0} END{ print min}'`

AVG1=`sar -r -f |awk '{print $5}'|grep -v '%memused'|grep -v '_x86_64_'|grep -v '86327'|awk '{total+=$0} END {print total/NR}'`

echo Minimum value is $MIN1 : average value is $AVG1 : maximum value is $MAX1
```

`sar -r -f` command o/p:

```
Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64 (servername)   11/03/2017      _x86_64_        (4 CPU)

12:00:01 AM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit

Average:       315191  32697953     99.05     86327  16937751  25889218     53.25
```

**script output:**

```
Minimum value is 95.50 : average value is 868.053 : maximum value is 86327
```

**Expected output:**

```
Minimum value is 95 : average value is 96 : maximum value is 97
```

I have skipped the value using `grep -v 86327` appearing in this last column but as it  as it varies every time my output will vary.

Comment: Please use code tags more clearly for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Following single `awk` may help you in same.

```
sar -r -f |  awk '
FNR>1&&!/memused/{
 max=max>$5?max:$5;
 min=min>$5?$5:(min?min:$5);
 sum+=$5}
END{
print "Minimum:",min,"Average:",(sum/FNR),"Maximum:",max
}'
```

***EDIT:*** Adding explanation for code too now.

```
sar -r -f |  awk '      ## Sending sar standard output as a standard input by pipe to awk command.
FNR>1&&!/memused/{      ## checking if line number is greater than and not having string memused in it then do following.
 max=max>$5?max:$5;     ## creating a variable named max and checking if max variable value is greater than 5th field then keep it as max else keep it as 5th field to get the maximum values.
 min=min>$5?$5:(min?min:$5); ##creating a variable named min and checking if min value is greater than 5th field if yes then change its value to $5 or check if min is there keep its value to min or if min is NULL then keep it as $5 value.
 sum+=$5}               ## creating variable named sum and adding its value to itself along with 5th fields value.
END{
print "Minimum:",min,"Average:",(sum/FNR),"Maximum:",max ##Printing string minimum and min value similarly with avg and maximum too.
}'
```

Comment: it is displaying o/p as Average: 812.191 Minimum: 95.50 Maximum: 84547 as last column of sar report showing o/p as Average:       313984  32699160     99.05     **84547**  16949896  25856886     53.19 i want to skip 84547 this value to get correct o/p as it varies everytime @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @ashish, sorry I didn't get it, could you please explain in details what is not correct here?

Comment: refer the sar o/p mentioned in my question the it is refering the last value in column kbbuffers i.e.84547 that will vary everytime so the o/p is coming wrong @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @ashish, ,my command is all together running on `sar` command and it is not build over your command, when I check it on my system it is giving exact output, not sure if you ran it on your system?

Comment: i have done few modification in your command and its working fine now thanks for the help @RavinderSingh13

Comment: can you just explain logic of this script?@RavinderSingh13

Comment: @ashish, Added my explanation successfully now, please check and let me know if you have any queries on same.

Comment: sum+=$5}  ## creating variable named sum and adding its value to itself along with 5th fields value i didn't got this ?@RavinderSingh13

Comment: @ashish, create a variable named sum and everytime add $5's value to it's value in all the lines(apart from 1st line and line which doesn't have string memused in it).